# Find all content that has Paragraph Content

Tags: 8, paragraphs

Is there any way to find all content that has any value in the field created by Paragraph module?

Looking to find content and move it into the Body field so that:

1. We don't loose the content.
2. We can delete the paragraph module.

Comment: The raw data of the paragraphs doesn't help much. If you want that the content looks the same as before I would build a view to export the rendered paragraphs and put the resulting HTML in the body field.

Answer (score 2):

For each field in drupal website, drupal creates a table in database with name `ENTITYTYPE__FIELDMACHINENAME`, so if you have applied a field called field_paragraph to a node type the table will name : `node__field_paragraph`, in that table there is a column called `entity_id` which indicates that data belongs to which entity in your website.

so you simply can write a query to fetch a list of all node having data for an specific field, or if you don't know how to write a query you can explore that table to check them manually.